# How to import into a C++/WinRT project a UserControl from a windows runtime component written in C#?

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, c++-winrt

I have a very simple windows runtime component project written in C# in my solution where I added a `UserControl` that I would like to export to a C++/WinRT project. 
This component works fine when imported into another C# project, but I get a compilation error when I try to import and use it in my C++/WinRT project.

```
\my_project\generated files\xamltypeinfo.g.cpp(1313): error C3083: 'my_component_XamlTypeInfo': the symbol to the left of a '::' must be a type
```

I added the reference to the component and I have added the following include to my `pch.h` thinking that it would resolve it:

`#include "winrt/my_component.h"`

but then I get the following compilation error:

```
\my_project\generated files\xamltypeinfo.g.cpp(1306): error C3083: 'my_component_XamlTypeInfo': the symbol to the left of a '::' must be a type
```

I noticed that there is also that if I include the header: 
`#include "winrt/data_grid.data_grid_XamlTypeInfo.h"`

I no longer get a compiler error but the app crashes at startup when it tries to instantiate the component.

What is the normal procedure for importing windows runtime components that include XAML into C++/WinRT apps?

Comment: Could your share a mini sample for testing ?

Comment: Here it is https://github.com/maximebl/BlankApp1. You can start by looking at how I import the component in MainPage.xaml. This works if BlankApp1 is a C# app, but not if it's a C++/WinRT app as you will see from this sample.

Comment: Great , I will test your project.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Did you manage to reproduce the issue on your end? (:

Comment: Have you tried a Templated control over a UserControl?

Comment: The result is exactly the same with a templated control